# get vagrant provider version in Vagrantfile and pass it to provisioner

Tags: shell, virtualbox, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

I'm trying to automate provisioning of the VBoxGuestAdditions at CentOS/7 guest on Ubuntu trusty64 host, and the best way I've found is to download the .iso directly from virtualbox.org, mount it and install the Additions.

It all works fine, but there is a catch I cannot figure out - I cannot get access to the exact version of virtualbox from within guest's shell provisioner to download the matching version of VBoxGuestAdditions.iso file.

So here's what exactly I'm doing:

In the Vagrantfile:

```
...
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provision.sh"
...
```

In the shell provisioner:

```
...
wget -c http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.36/VBoxGuestAdditions_4.3.36.iso -O /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
mount /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso -o loop /mnt
sh /opt/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run --nox11
rm /opt/*.iso
chkconfig --add vboxadd
chkconfig vboxadd on
...
```

And the problem is with `4.3.36` in the VBoxGuestAdditions_4.3.36.iso download path.

I can pass arguments to shell provisioner via

```
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provision.sh", :args => <args>
```

in the Vagrantfile, but I can't see how I could get the actual version string from the host machine in here to pass it over to provisioner on the guest.

Something like

```
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provision.sh", :args => "--provider-version="+config.vm.provider.version
```

would be ideal, but that doesn't work afaik.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out that I was asking the wrong question. The real answer is [vagrant-vbguest](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest) plugin. It handles VBoxGuestAdditions installation transparently and spares us from handling it in provisioning.